# How do I open .bin/.idx database files?

Tags: windows, database

I'm attempting to open some database files used by a legacy application that I know almost nothing about. The databases appear to be in file pairs of a *bin* and *idx*, for example: ***Cust.bin*** and ***Cust.idx***.

I have never seen this type of database before and wasn't able to find anything useful through Google. I also don't know what language or tool the developer used for this app, but it seems that he used the default generic icon for his published executable. This is it:

[image: Programs Icon]

Can anyone tell me anything about this application, what type of database it uses and how I might open the database myself?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information; at least the name of the program or something else to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program that was using this database was a custom written application by a former consultant.

I never did figure out what type of database he was using, or how to open it properly. But I did manage to extract all the data out of it. I opened the file up in EditPad and found that all records had fixed-length fields. With this knowledge I was able to easily write a small application to parse all the binary data and export everything to .csv

So I was ultimately able to get the data. Woot!